# spring security - change logout success url dynamically

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm developing a java spring mvc project. This is a part of my securityConfig class:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            ....
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/loginForm")
            ...
}
```

When a user logs out, spring redirects him to the `loginForm` page. But, I want to change this url, dynamically. In fact, I want to redirect users to different pages based on some conditions. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4):

See [LogoutSuccessHandler](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.9.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/logout/LogoutSuccessHandler.html):

> Strategy that is called after a successful logout by the `LogoutFilter`, to handle redirection or forwarding to the appropriate destination.

For Java Configuration see [LogoutConfigurer#logoutSuccessHandler](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.2.3.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configurers/LogoutConfigurer.html#logoutSuccessHandler(org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutSuccessHandler)).

Your modified source code:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .logout().logoutSuccessHandler(myLogoutSuccessHandler);
}
```